Can somebody help me understand this piece of x86 assembly?
I need to convert a piece of code to SIMD using intrincics.
So I first looked at the disassembly of then none-SIMD code.
And I see that the compiler seems to do some tricks I do not understand.
This is the disassembly (sorry could not copy-paste, only screen shot worked):

Can somebody help me explain this?
I do not understand how this line is compiled: chk = x ^ (x<<1);
(x is a 32 bit signed integer. The sign bit is xored with the bit right to it)
And how the compare for <0 is done after that.

Technically, chk < 0 can only happen if x<<1 overflows, which is UB for signed integers. A clever compiler could remove that check completely ...

@chtz good news: in C++23 that is no longer UB (but this question doesn't say what language that code is in)

@harold can you point me to a reference for that? And does this mean that foo(int) is wrongly optimized here: https://godbolt.org/z/3zhq4Ts31 ?

@chtz see [expr.shift] in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4928.pdf that foo is not affected by this change since there is no shift in it

The lea eax, [rcx + rcx] is doing eax = ecx + ecx = 2 * ecx = ecx << 1 which is your x << 1.
The xor eax, ecx then calculates the x ^ (x << 1). The xor edx, 7FFFFFFFh does what it says.
Finally the cmovns edx, ecx conditionally undoes that xor.
The code more closely corresponds to:
int32_t chk = x + x;   // lea eax, [rcx + rcx]
int32_t res = x;       // mov edx, ecx
res ^= 0x7FFFFFFF;     // xor edx, 7FFFFFFFh
chk ^= x;              // xor eax, ecx
if (chk >= 0) res = x; // cmovns edx, ecx


The first lea is x << 1. See similar questions, like Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers? and What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?
Further it computes both and uses cmovcc (cmovns here) to overwrite one result with another depending on a condition. Using cmovcc makes the resulting assembly branchless.
